# Apache Camel BindException: "Can't Assign Requested Address"

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

I am in the process of learning how to use Camel. I am having an issue with the following snippet of code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FeefooExampleApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(FeefooExampleApplication.class, args);

        CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();
        camelContext.addRoutes(new CamelConfig());
        camelContext.start();


        Blah blah = new Blah();

        blah.getFeefoData();

    }
}
```

My CamelConfig Class is the following:

```
package com.example.camel;


import com.example.feefo.FeedbackProcessor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;


public class CamelConfig extends RouteBuilder {


    private FeedbackProcessor feedbackProcessor = new FeedbackProcessor();

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
       from("jetty:http://cdn2.feefo.com/api/xmlfeedback?merchantidentifier=example-retail-merchant")
           .convertBodyTo(String.class)
           .bean(feedbackProcessor, "processFeedback")  ;

    }
}
```

The error that is reported is the following: 'Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address'

Would anybody be able to help ?

Thank You

Comment: Entire stacktrace please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When used as a consumer, the `jetty` component create an HTTP server, listening to a HTTP request, and creating an exchange with this request.

In other words, when you do `from("jetty:http://cdn2.feefo.com/..")`, you are asking jetty to create an HTTP server with the network interface associated to "cdn2.feefo.com": This fails (well, I have assumed your machine is not this host)

If you want to request this HTTP address, you have to use jetty (or the http4 component) as a producer. For example:

```
from("direct:check_xmlfeedback")
  .to("jetty:http://cdn2.feefo.com/api/xmlfeedback?merchantidentifier=example-retail-merchant")
  ...
```

and call your route with :

```
context.getProducerTemplate().requestBody("direct:check_xmlfeedback", null);
```

If you want to periodically poll this HTTP address, you can use the `timer` component:

```
from("timer:check?period=5m")
  .to("jetty:http://cdn2.feefo.com/api/xmlfeedback?merchantidentifier=example-retail-merchant")
  ...
```